# Trying to get data from Json object

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have this structure of JSON: {

```
-some_name: {
    - data: {
          id: "0ca497ef",
          status: "success"
    },
   - other_name: [
         -{
            id: "id1",
            title: "title1"
         },
         -{
             id: "id2",
             title: "title2"
         } 
    ]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the data using Volley, what I've done so far is not working:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.GET, "url", null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {

                                JSONArray jsonArrayresponse = response.getJSONArray("some_name");
                                String[] titles=null;
                                txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

                                for (int i=0;i<jsonArrayresponse.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject result = jsonArrayresponse.getJSONObject(i);
                                    JSONArray jsonArrayresult = result.getJSONArray("other_name");

                                    for (int y=0;y<jsonArrayresponse.length();y++) {
                                        String title= result.getString("title");

                                        titles[y] = title;
                                        txt.append(titles[i]);
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
                        }
                    }
            );

            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

So in this code, I am trying to get the first array(some_name), then the second array inside it (other_name) then add all the titles to a textView.

Can someone please point out what I did wrong and try to explain in a easy way because I am a beginner,
Thank you

Comment: Change **JSONArray jsonArrayresponse = response.getJSONArray("some_name");** to **JSONObject jsonObjectresponse = response.getJSONObject("some_name");**

Answer (score 1):

Well what you marked as

> some_name

Is not a JSON Array, but a JSON Object.